# Padding a single cell without effecting the whole row?

Tags: css, margin, padding

I want all the 100's to be aligned together, but the red box make it unaligned. I've tried padding that single cell, but it effects the whole row. 
how do I do this?

[See this fiddle,](http://jsfiddle.net/s5fhLne6/)

It says my question is mostly code so I have to add this paragraph as well.

html:

```
    <div id="marg">
    <div class="wrap">
      <table border="1" class="fixed">
        <col style="width:90px;" />
        <col style="width:160px;" />
        <col style="width:100px;" />
        <col style="width:115px;" />
        <col style="width:100px;" />
        <col style="width:130px;" />
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td style="padding-top:2em">100 <div class="good">Good</div></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>    
  </div>
```

css:

```
table.fixed td, th {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#marg .wrap table table {
    width: 100%}

#marg table.fixed {
    table-layout: fixed;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:.95em;
}

#marg table {
    table-layout: auto;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    empty-cells: show;
}
#marg td, th {
    color: #556B7D;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E9E0E1;
    border-left: 1px solid #E9E0E1;
    text-align: left;
    padding: .4em .7em 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
th {
    background-color: #900;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    vertical-align: middle;
}
table {
    border-top: 1px solid #E9E0E1;
    border-right: 1px solid #E9E0E1;
    background-color: #F4F2F3;
    background-color: #F2F3F4;
}
.good {
    font-size: .85em;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #C03;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 70px;
    height: 16px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
table.fixed p {
    margin-top: 3px;
}
.wrap {
    width: 695px;
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? They are all the specified widths are they not?

Comment: I'm not talking about width. I want the text inside each cell (100's) to be aligned together. in the fiddle, I can manually align them by padding that single cell, but then the whole row is getting padded as well. hope it's more clear now. basically the red box is causing them to be unaligned.

Comment: The title says “padding”, the text says “aligned”, without specifying what it means to align items on the same row. You should present a minimal document that still demonstrates the problem and state the problem clearly. What should be aligned to what?

Comment: like I said, 100's are to be aligned, all in the same height, and i was trying to achieve this with padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the padding on that cell and change `vertical-align: middle` on your `td` and `th`s to `vertical-align: top`

http://jsfiddle.net/s5fhLne6/1/

Comment: Thanks. only problem is what if I want to create a third row, that would be aligned to the middle? I managed to acheive this only by creating two classes (each for each align), and assign every single cell in the table with the particular class.

Comment: It vertically aligns the content inside of a `td` or a `th`. Adding more rows shouldn't change that functionality

Answer (score 0):

I just run your code and the 100s are all aligned since you used the internal style. Try your code here http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_styles_internal.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the 100's to div element and set class like .alone for example:

```
.alone
{
vertical-align:bottom;
height:70px;
}

.good {
    font-size: .85em;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #C03;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 70px;
    height: 16px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

try this one [here!](http://jsfiddle.net/s5fhLne6/2/)